# animated bottom navigation bar using flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, bottom-navigation-bar

I want to create an animated bottom navigationbar like show in the image below. How can I do that?

[bot_nav_bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hbekp.gif)

Comment: [Here's](https://pub.dev/packages/curved_navigation_bar) your answer.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Unfortunatley this package wont work for me bc the selected item is elevated to the top and I can't change that. Also does the package not have the option to disable the curve animation.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/animated_bottom_navigation_bar

Comment: You can easily customize a package's code in your project, just make the required changes in its code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.